# onClick function not working using context-api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-context

The `handleDetail()` function for clicking a product and pulling up the product detail page isn't working. My `addToCart` function is working properly so I don't know what I'm missing.

context.js:

```
state = {
  products: [],
  productDataDetail: productDataDetail,
};

getItem = (id) => {
  const product = this.state.products.find((item) => item.id === id);
  return product;
};

handleDetails = id => {
  const product = this.getItem(id);
  this.setState(() => {
    return { productDataDetail: product };
  });
};

render() {
  return (
    <ProductContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...this.state,
        handleDetails: this.handleDetails,
      }}
    >
      {this.props.children}
    </ProductContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

product.js:

```
<ProductConsumer>
  {(value) => (
    <Card className={classes.root}>
      <CardActionArea onClick={() => value.handleDetails(id)}>
  )}
</ProductConsumer>
```

Product Data:

```js
export const productDataDetail = {
  id: 0,
  name: "Desk",
  img: desk,
  store: "Local Furniture Shop 1",
  price: 9.99,
  desc:
    "This sturdy desk is built to outlast years of coffee and hard work. You get a generous work surface and a clever solution to keep cords in place underneath.",
  inCart: false,
  count: 0,
  total: 0,
};
```

Answer (score 2):

`bind` it:

```js
        value={{
          ...this.state,
          handleDetails: this.handleDetails.bind(this)
        }}
```

Otherwise, when you call `value.handleDetails`, the function is bound to a different context (`value`) than the one you intended (the component's context)